What is the best way to understand if nRF24L01+ still works properly?
I continuously transmit some data from one nRF24L01+ (nRF) to another one. After a long transmission time, I often experience that the transmitter stops its transmission at a random time for no reason. When I reset the MCU (Arduino Nano), the transmission starts again. I can probably handle this problem by performing a reconnection via SPI. But first, I must find out when the transmission is stopped.
How can I understand If nRF still works properly? Is there any register query for this via SPI?
Thanks

Shouldn't you be packetizing the data? Are you overloading the buffer in the chip?

stops transmission for no reason ... there is always a reason

@Andyaka I packet the data into the payload following its rules. Actually, I don't care about the stopped transmission phenomena. I just want to restart the transmission process after detecting the stopped nRF functioning. I want to learn a good method to capture the nRF when it stops doing what I said.

@jsotola Most probably, the reason is that our modules are not original Nordic products. It is my guest, I am not sure. That's why I don't try to solve the weird and sudden malfunctioning problem.
